# How to install composer.json in Yii1 project?

Tags: php, yii, composer-php

i have an existing Yii1 project but without the assets folder. So only the folders: css, images, protected.

So I made just an empty composer.json file in the root directory. And I did a

```
composer install
```

But then I get this error:

```
 "./composer.json" does not contain valid JSON
  Parse error on line 1:

  ^
  Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

And yes, of course I have read the offical documentation for composer:

https://getcomposer.org

But I can't find how I then can run composer install.

Thank you

Comment: Well, what's in it?

Comment: It is empty. I just made in the root a empty composer.json file. I already installed of course composer. Because if I do this:  composer -v  it returns Composer version 2.3.3 2022-04-01 22:15:35

Comment: And is it not that if you do comoser install that then automatically the composer.json file will be generated?

Comment: Well maybe you should install some packages, otherwise `composer install` will do nothing

Comment: Oke, I used a existing composer.json file for Yii1 from github and now it has installed the vendor folder

Comment: Oke, good, so it works?

Comment: Yes, the installation works now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke, I used a existing composer.json file for Yii1 from github and now it has installed the vendor folder